# ApplicationController how to execute code on each page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to execute some ruby code on each page of my application! I putet the hole code into my application controller:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery

 if Setting.exists?(1) 
 @setting = Setting.find(1) 
 else 
 redirect_to new_setting_path
 end 

 end
```

This somehow wont work! The strange thing is that when i put the hole code into my application html it works:

```
<body>
<% if Setting.exists?(1) 
@setting = Setting.find(1) 
else 
redirect_to new_setting_path
end %>
```

What do i have to change in my application controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ApplicationController is the correct place, but you should put your code in a before_filter :

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery

   before_filter :ensure_setting

   private

   def ensure_setting
    @setting = Setting.where( id: 1 ).first or redirect_to( new_setting_path )
   end
 end
```

Comment: I think a protected method would be better here, because you could overwrite it in the controller you want to "bypass" this method. (protected = usable for the class & descendants, private = only for the class)

Comment: Very nice code and very short!!! But why do i have to call private? Maybe you can explain me this! Im beginner in rails! Thanks in advance

Comment: One more thing!! How can i say that def ensure_seetings should not be called on the site new_setting_path ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji : that's not how protected works in ruby : private can indeed be accessed by subclasses. Protected only means [other instances from the same class can access the method](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_access_control.html). That is almost never wanted, so I always use private.

Comment: @user2724695 : it's private mostly for coding convention : it is not supposed to be accessed by a route, like would be `#index`, #new`, etc (and won't be if a route was matching it in any way).

Comment: @user2724695 you can skip the filter in `settings#new` by putting on top of SettingsController : `skip_before_filter :ensure_setting, only: :new`